# how to create a category with wp_insert_post and post_category

Tags: posts, categories, wp-insert-post

I am trying to create a post with php and its wordpress functions.

I am using wp_insert_post () but I can not assign a custom category type text to the post nor create it

I have this code:

```
require_once 'wp-load.php';
// This is test snippet for learning purposes.
// Creates a WordPress Post with code.
$post_id = -1;
// Set the Author, Slug, title and content of the new post

$category=get_cat_ID( 'Samsung' );
$author_id = 1;
$slug = 'wordpress-post-created-with-code';
$title = 'WordPress post created whith code';
$content = 'This is the content of the post that we are creating right now with code. 
            More text: I motsetning til hva mange tror, er ikke Lorem Ipsum bare tilfeldig tekst. 
            ';
$post_id = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
        'post_category'     =>  array($category),
        'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
        'post_name'         =>  $slug,
        'post_title'        =>  $title,
        'post_content'      =>  $content,
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'post_type'         =>  'post'


    )


);
```

As you can see I can not assign the category "Samsung" and in case there is no category then create it
Any idea how to do it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to add existing term or new term to post you need to use `wp_set_post_terms` by checking with `term_exists` and using `wp_insert_term` if it doesn't.

Something like this:

```
$author_id = 1;
$slug = 'wordpress-post-created-with-code';
$title = 'WordPress post created whith code';
$content = 'This is the content of the post that we are creating right now with code. 
            More text: I motsetning til hva mange tror, er ikke Lorem Ipsum bare tilfeldig tekst.';
$post_id = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'comment_status'    =>  'closed',
        'post_author'       =>  $author_id,
        'post_name'         =>  $slug,
        'post_title'        =>  $title,
        'post_content'      =>  $content,
        'post_status'       =>  'publish',
        'post_type'         =>  'post'
    )
);
$taxonomy = '<CUSTOM_TAXONOMY_SLUG>';
if (term_exists('samsung', $taxonomy)) {
    $terms = array('samsung');
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, true);
} else {
    $term = 'samsung';
    $inserted_term = wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy);
    if(!is_wp_error($inserted_term)) {
        wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $term, $taxonomy, true);
    }
}
```